# Permanently add submodules files to main repository

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a plain repository $main, without submodules. Inside it I add the library $lib into /3rdparty/$lib using `git clone`.

Also $lib repository contains several submodules which I initialize and update.

So $main noticed that $lib's  submodules are submobules and won't push theirs files into the $main.

Can I permanently add this submodules into $main?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $lib is a submodule (as you said that you clone it I suppose so), $lib should be recoqnized as a git-repo and added as a submodule, $lib itself should track its own submodules.

$main should never find anything inside $lib, there's something wrong if it does.

Technically you should be able to add a submodule to the superproject and to as a submodule to one of the superprojects submodules, however it might conflict during checkouts and worktree updates and it's really bad taste.

You should also use git submodule add and not do a git clone in the superproject. A git submodule add (and submodule init/update etc.) will place the .git-dir inside the superprojects .git-dir which will allow git to handle the submodules better (delete them from the worktree when they are not needed for example).

And as a bottom line, you can't push files, you can add changes to files to commit and you can push commits.

Comment: $lib is not submodule for $main, I manually clone $lib into directory inside $main, so $main find $lib's files but not find files of $lib's submodules. I see that manual adding repos is a bad practice, but I really need to avoid submodules. (Because main project don't use submodules, so build server get source by git clone without submodules init, and I don't have access to build server settings.) Don't you have any ideas how to hide submodule essential of $lib submodules from $main, or any other way to avoid submodules?

Comment: There's something wrong here, you should really not see the files inside $lib (neither in $libs submodules) as git will threat git-repos inside the worktree as submodules (added or not).

The replacement for submodules are subtrees, look at:
http://git-scm.com/book/ch6-7.html

However I suggest that you fix your buildsystem. There's of course other bad solutions, like removing or hiding the .git-dirs and add everything as regular files and then reclone when you need to update them.

Comment: Well I'll try subtrees, thank you. I wonder why git clone not get all source recursively by default.